# Auto retrieval of data in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have a log in page shown below
[image: Login page for admin]

Admin only has a permission to access this page and he creates a new user with the following requirements.

when the particular user login his page is shown below

[image: User login page]

I need to retrieve the Faculty id,so that it should me automatically displayed in the textbox.

for that i need to call from datbase.? or is there any text box property to display the data ?

I am using asp.net withc#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(Connection_String);
SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand(Command, Conn);
Conn.Open();
textBox.Text = Comm1.ExecuteScalar();
Conn.Close();
```

Comment: Wrap your all statements in `!IsPostBack` condition on page load.